# I have been at this error for a long time while building my chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notion-api

The error  `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@notionhq/client". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

to understand my code

notion.js

```
import config from './config.js'
import { Client } from '@notionhq/client';

// Initialize the Notion client
const notion = new Client({
  auth: config.NOTION_API_TOKEN, // Use the environment variable for API key
});

// Retrieve the database ID from the environment variable
const databaseId = config.NOTION_DATABASE_ID;

// Function to create a new bookmark page in Notion
async function createBookmarkPage(bookmarkData) {
  try {
    const response = await notion.pages.create({
      parent: {
        database_id: databaseId,
      },
      properties: {
        title: {
          title: [
            {
              text: {
                content: bookmarkData.title,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        languages: {
          rich_text: [
            {
              text: {
                content: bookmarkData.languages,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        url: {
          url: bookmarkData.url,
        },
        tags: {
          multi_select: bookmarkData.tags.split(',').map(tag => ({ name: tag.trim() })),
        },
        notes: {
          rich_text: [
            {
              text: {
                content: bookmarkData.notes,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });

    console.log('Bookmark page created:', response);
    return response; // Return the created page data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating bookmark page:', error);
    throw error; // Throw the error for the caller to handle
  }
}

// Export the createBookmarkPage function
export default {
  createBookmarkPage,
};
```

popup.js

```
import notion from './notion.js';

const createBookmarkPage = notion.createBookmarkPage;


document.getElementById("bookmarkForm").addEventListener("submit", async function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Retrieve form values
  var title = document.getElementsByName("title")[0].value;
  var languages = document.getElementsByName("languages")[0].value;
  var url = document.getElementsByName("url")[0].value;
  var tags = document.getElementsByName("tags")[0].value;
  var notes = document.getElementsByName("notes")[0].value;

  // Create an object with the bookmark data
  var bookmark = {
    title: title,
    languages: languages,
    url: url,
    tags: tags,
    notes: notes,
  };
  console.log(bookmark);

  try {
    // Call the createBookmarkPage function
    await createBookmarkPage(bookmark);
    console.log('Bookmark page created successfully');
    // Perform additional actions or show success message
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating bookmark page:', error);
    // Handle errors and show error message
  }

  // Clear form inputs
  document.getElementById("bookmarkForm").reset();
});
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/static/css/3111790e63d7a482.css" />
  <title>Create Next App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" sizes="any" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="max-w-md mx-auto p-4">
    <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Save to Notion Bookmarks</h1>
    <form id="bookmarkForm">
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="block mb-1">Title</label>
        <input type="text" title="" required="" class="w-full border border-gray-300 px-2 py-1 rounded" name="title" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="block mb-1">Languages</label>
        <input type="text" class="w-full border border-gray-300 px-2 py-1 rounded" name="languages" />
        <small>Separate Languages with Commas</small>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="block mb-1">URL</label>
        <input type="url" title="" required="" class="w-full border border-gray-300 px-2 py-1 rounded" name="url" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="block mb-1">Tags</label>
        <input type="text" class="w-full border border-gray-300 px-2 py-1 rounded" name="tags" />
        <small>Separate Tags with Commas</small>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-4">
        <label class="block mb-1">Notes</label>
        <textarea name="notes" rows="3" class="w-full border border-gray-300 px-2 py-1 rounded"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded"><span>Save</span></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  
  <script type="module" src="./notion.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="./popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Notion Bookmarks",
  "short_name": "notion-bookmark",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Store Links to Notion",
  "icons": {
    "16": "/icon-16.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.notion.so https://cdn.jsdelivr.net"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "inject.js"
      ]
      
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried lot of stuff from bundling to everything but what I think is there is an issue to access Client in

```
import { Client } from '@notionhq/client';
```

but when i use that and reference to the intended file in the modulelike this

```
import { Client } from './node_modules/@notionhq/client/build/src/index.d.ts';
```

it gives me error like
`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Has anyone else faced this ???

Comment: To use this syntax of import you must compile the file in webpack or a similar bundler. The fact that you see an error means you didn't compile everything or you look at an old error in chrome://extensions, which you can remove by clicking the trashcan icon. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.